# Test result of asyncronous Ajax call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a function using jQuery like so:

```
function populate_messages_node() {
    $.ajax({url: "/messages", type: "GET", success: populate_recent_messages});
}
```

I want to write an integration test for this function. My problem is that the test:

```
function test_simple() {
    populate_messages_node();
    // assert node content here
}
```

... will not wait for the Ajax success method (populate_recent_messages) to do its stuff. For this trivial example, doing `$.ajaxSetup({async:false})` works, but I fear that will not always be true. There will be a large number of such tests for scenarios more complicated for this.

I guess my question really is: is there no way to wait on completion of XHR/Websocket operations in Javascript?

I would prefer not to modify production code (populate_messages_node), but returning the xhr result from .ajax() is prolly OK. (I apologize in advance for not having found the canonical SO post that surely describes exactly this problem.)

Comment: Test frameworks normally provide ways to handle asynchronous tests.

Comment: You can set async to false. Not really in the spirit of testing your site properly though. You may want to harness the magic of callbacks and the ability to attach to events to allow your tests to integrate with your framework.

Comment: @FelixKling: my test framework is not specific to jQuery tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) from `populate_message_node()` then hook to the complete event as follows.

```
function populate_messages_node() {
    return $.ajax({url: "/messages", type: "GET", success: populate_recent_messages});
}

function test_simple() {
    populate_messages_node().complete(function(jqxhr){ 
    // assert node content here
    });
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could wrap the .ajax() function with some infrastructure to make this somewhat more stylish and avoid the return statement.

Comment: Bittrance, there's many ways to go about it but since you said you didn't want to change the production code much this is what i suggested.